# What does -h flag mean in winget?

Tags: powershell, winget

I was working with **WinGet**, when I suddenly noticed why we write '**-h**' in command.

What is the use of this flag? I tried searching but couldn't find.

[image]

Comment: Did you notice any difference without `-h`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `winget <subcommand-h> -?` to see all options for that command.

```bash
PS> winget upgrade -? | Select-String '-h\b'

  -h,--silent                          Request silent installation
```

You can also find the information online:

- [`winget.exe` main page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget)
- The subcommands have their own pages, linked from the main page.

  - To get directly to a subcommand's page, append the subcommand name to the main-page URL, e.g. [`winget upgrade`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade)
  - To jump directly to the list of options, append `#options`; e.g. [`winget upgrade` options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/upgrade#options)